# How to extract latest reply text from email, and cut out previous messages?

Tags: c#, .net, email, openpop

I am using **OpenPop.dll** to read emails in my application. I want to read only the reply of the email not original email which it was replied to. But email is read with previous emails in quotes. I want to remove those previous mail contents.

I tried using RegEx for this but that is not very robust way to read replies because different email clients have different reply format.

Is there any way by which I can read only the reply text from mail thread in OpenPop.dll or some other open source library.

Below is how the reply email text looks like when read from OpenPop.dll.

```
My phone number is 123456789.

On Fri, May 8, 2015 at 2:57 PM,  wrote:

>  Hi,
>
> This mail is regarding your *Phone*. Please reply to this email with your
> *Phone*.
>
> Thanks
>
```

This format is such that because it was replied from Gmail. Outlook has different format and so does yahoo.

I want to read only

```
My phone number is 123456789.
```

Is there any way I could achieve this? Any solution is welcome.

Comment: I fixed this by switching to different emailing API [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) . This API allows you to get only the replied content from the incoming mail.

Answer (score -2):

I faced with such a problem.I did data mining.I used naive Bayes algorithm.You need email data collection.Problem will be solved.
This is my project. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJShFuEEsQg

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Firstly,I collected  email reply data from gmail,hotmail,yahoo  etc. I used these email reply datas for  make text classification with Naive Bayes algorithm.I convert html email to text. I divide the text line by line.I did classification each line with Naive Bayes algorithm.I cleaned the unnecessary part inside the text.